# PUT method for Symfony firewall form_login paths

Tags: symfony, authentication

I'm configuring the Symfony firewall to handle a login form. The trick is that the check route **must** use the PUT method, not POST.

This is the part of my firewall configuration that is related to my problem:

```
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            provider: customer

            form_login:
                login_path: api_user_login
                check_path: api_user_login_connect
```

As you can see, I don't use paths but routes instead. Mainly because I need to specify the method for the check_path (PUT in my case)

Here is my `api_user_login_connect` route:

```
api_user_login_connect:
    path:     /users
    defaults: { _controller: ApiBundle:Login:connect }
    methods:  [PUT]
```

Symfony issues an error when I try to access `/users`, saying that there is no route for `/users` (in GET I assume). So I understand that the firewall won't let me use the PUT method for the `check_path` route, or that it doesn't read the whole route from the configuration, but just the path that is defined in the route.

**How can I tell Symfony firewall to check credentials using a PUT request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*We found the answer before I posted this question, here it is...*

For the firewall to accept login check on methods other than GET, you must this option: `post_only: false`. It's true by default.

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider: customer
        post_only: false
```